# Dataframe pyspark to dictionary after groupby operations

Tags: python, dictionary, pyspark

I am looking to solve the following issue in **pyspark**.

I have a huge dataset on which I would like to compute basic statistics which have to be stored in a dictionary.

The dataset is approximately depicted in the table below even though in reality its way bigger.

The datatype of the target data I am interested in is either a string or a double.

```
|  key1  | ... | key2   | key3   | value1 | ... | value2 | 
|--------|-----|--------|--------|--------|-----|--------| 
| string | ... | string | string | double | ... | double |
```

I have to perform a groupBy on [key1, key2, key3] and compute the mean and the standard deviation of both value1 and value2.

Then, I want to store all the results in a dictionary with the following structure:

```
dict {[key1, key2, key3]  :  [avg1, sd1, avg2, sd2]}
```

My initial approach was to perform the calculations first, something like:

```
sparkdf.groupBy(keys).agg(avg(v1), stddev(v1), avg(v2), stddev(v2))
```

then convert the resulting sparkdf to pandasdf and loop over rows in order to build the dict. But for big datasets I highly doubt that this approach will be reasonable.

I learned that one way of doing this would be by making use of maps and UDFs.

For example:

```
sparkdf.groupBy(keys)
       .agg(collect_list(create_map([avg1, sd1, avg2, sd2]).alias('map')))

map = udf(lambda maps: {key:r[key] for r in map for key in r}, 
                 MapType( StringType(), DoubleType())

dict = do something with the map
```

This kind of solution is what was being discussed in this topic ([Dataframe pyspark to dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47656180/dataframe-pyspark-to-dict)).

**However**, in my case I do not have the values [avg1, sd1, avg2, sd2] which need to be computed using the groupBy operation. Since methods like collect_list and create_map are used, I cannot put avg(v1) inside those or I will be thrown a error back.

Can anybody suggest how would you go about building the dict I need?

Many thanks!

Comment: The methods toLocalIterator() and convert the Row objects to dict using row.asDict() will be helpful in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your output dictionary is small enough to fit in your master node memory, and assuming `keys` is a list of key field names, this should work (though I have not run it, so there might be typos):

```
aggregatedSparkDf = sparkdf.groupBy(keys).agg(avg(v1), stddev(v1), avg(v2), stddev(v2))
aggregatedPandasDf = aggregatedSparkDf.toPandas().set_index(keys)
aggregatedPandasSeriesOfLists = aggregatedPandasDf.apply(list, result_type='reduce', axis=1)
aggregatedDict = aggregatedPandasSeriesOfLists.to_dict()
```

This should get you a dict {(key1,key2,key3}:[avg1,std1,avg2,std2]).

But why would you want to convert to a dictionary?  Most likely you're better off working with the pandas DF.