# Create a dictionary from spark table

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

As the title states, I'm attempting to generate a dictionary out of a spark table to be used as a broadcast variable, but as a novice in this area I'm struggling to figure out the proper way to do this.

The dictionary structure I'm aiming for looks something like this. The main purpose is to create a "lookup" table that I can use to find the nearest match within a group of data and return the Parent for that rank.

```
{
  '1603756800': {
    'B000GIPJY8': [
      {
        'Rank': 43,
        'ParentAsin':'B08LX475MX'
      },      
      {
        'Rank': 146,
        'ParentAsin':'B08LXSRY8R'
      },
      {
        'Rank': 1320,
        'ParentAsin':'B08LL7LDYN'
      },
      {
        'Rank': 2471,
        'ParentAsin':'B08LLC2TWN'
      },
      {
        'Rank': 4058,
        'ParentAsin':'B08LX4D9CR'
      }
    ]
 }},
{
  '1603756800': {
    'B000GIQSV6': [
      {
        'Rank': 37,
        'ParentAsin':'B08LKB3H7L'
      },      
      {
        'Rank': 1320,
        'ParentAsin':'B08LLBCDT8'
      }
    ]
 }}
```

BroadcastDf

```
+----------+-------+----------+----------+
|  tmp_Asin|US_Rank|ParentAsin|     Epoch|
+----------+-------+----------+----------+
|B000GIQSV6|   38.0|B08LKB3H7L|1603324800|
|B000GIQSV6|32841.0|B08LLBCDT8|1603324800|
|B000GIQSV6|   37.0|B08LKB3H7L|1603324800|
|B000GIPJY8|30153.0|B08LLBCDT8|1603324800|
|B000GIPJY8|   37.0|B08LKB3H7L|1603324800|
|B000GIQSV6| 2735.0|B08LLC2TWN|1603324800|
|B000GIPJY8|   38.0|B08LKB3H7L|1603324800|
|B000GIQSV6|30153.0|B08LLBCDT8|1603324800|
|B000GIPJY8| 2735.0|B08LLC2TWN|1603324800|
|B000GIPJY8|32841.0|B08LLBCDT8|1603324800|
+----------+-------+----------+----------+
```

Piecing a couple SO answers together I was able to come up with this.

```
def findNearest(asin, us_Rank, epoch):
  if epoch in list(broadcastVar.value.keys()):
    asins = broadcastVar.value[epoch]
    if asin in asins.keys():
      variations = broadcastVar.value[epoch][asin]
      lowest = 0
      parent = ''

      for variation in variations:
        vRank = variation['Rank']
        vParent = variation['ParentAsin']

        diff = abs((vRank - us_Rank))

        if lowest == 0 or lowest > diff:
          lowest = diff
          parent = vParent

      return parent
  else:
    return ''

combineMap = F.udf(lambda maps:{key:f[key] for f in maps for key in f},
             T.MapType( T.DoubleType(), T.StringType()))

combineDeepMap = udf(lambda maps: {key:f[key] for f in maps for key in f},
              T.MapType(T.StringType(), T.MapType(T.DoubleType(), T.StringType())))

mapdf = broadcastDf.filter("tmp_Asin == 'B000GIPJY8' OR tmp_Asin == 'B000GIQSV6' ").groupBy('Epoch', 'tmp_Asin') \
                   .agg(F.collect_list(F.create_map('US_Rank','ParentAsin')).alias('maps')) \
                   .agg(combineDeepMap(F.collect_list(F.create_map('Epoch', combineMap('maps')))))

result_dict = mapdf.collect()[0][0]

broadcastVar = sc.broadcast(result_dict)
print(broadcastVar.value)
```

```
{'1603065600': {
161.0: 'B08L65HM35', 40.0: 'B08L6CRR2S', 41.0: 'B08L6CRR2S', 45.0: 'B08L6CRR2S'},
 '1603497600': {
40.0: 'B08LKB3H7L', 167.0: 'B08LLBCDT8', 42.0: 'B08LKB3H7L', 2725.0: 'B08LLC2TWN', 45.0: 'B08LKB3H7L'}}
```

```
udf_FindNearest = F.udf(findNearest, T.StringType())

toLookUp = asinscanpy.withColumn("Epoch", F.unix_timestamp(F.col("ScanDate")))\
                      .select("Asin", "US_Rank", "ParentAsin", "NoBB", "ScanDate", "Timestamp", "Epoch").where(F.col("ParentAsin").isNull()).where(F.col("Asin") == 'B000GIPJY8').where(F.col("ScanDate") >= '2020-10-01').where(F.col("US_Rank") > 0.0)\
                      .withColumn("ParentAsin", udf_FindNearest(F.col("Asin"), F.col("US_Rank"), F.col("Epoch").cast(T.StringType()))).show()
```

Its pretty close, but I'm now stuck on how to include my tmp_Asin column into the mix. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47656180/dataframe-pyspark-to-dict

Comment: Thanks Steven but, that link has gotten me where I'm at now. My dictionary requires an extra layer of nesting for tmp_Asin, I'm pretty sure I need to define an additional udf to hold epoch : tmp_Asin as well as modify combineDeepMap to fit the additional fields.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be my solution

```
def findNearest(asin, us_Rank, epoch):
  if epoch in list(broadcastVar.value.keys()):
    asins = broadcastVar.value[epoch]
    if asin in asins.keys():
      variations = broadcastVar.value[epoch][asin]
      lowest = 0
      parent = ''
      
      for key in variations:
        vRank = key
        vPAsin = variations[key]
        
        diff = abs((vRank - us_Rank))

        if lowest == 0 or lowest > diff:
          lowest = diff
          parent = vPAsin
      
      return parent
  else:
    return ''

combineMap = F.udf(lambda maps:{key:f[key] for f in maps for key in f},
             T.MapType( T.DoubleType(), T.StringType()))

combineDeepMap = udf(lambda maps: {key:f[key] for f in maps for key in f},
              T.MapType(T.StringType(), T.MapType(T.StringType(), T.MapType(T.DoubleType(), T.StringType()))))


mapdf = broadcastDf.filter("ScanDate >= '2020-10-01'").groupBy('Epoch','tmp_Asin') \
                     .agg(F.collect_list(F.create_map('US_Rank','ParentAsin')).alias('maps'))\
                     .agg(combineDeepMap(F.collect_list(F.create_map(F.col('Epoch').cast(T.StringType()), F.create_map('tmp_Asin', combineMap('maps'))) ))).alias('Dict')

result_dict = mapdf.collect()[0][0]
broadcastVar = sc.broadcast(result_dict)

udf_FindNearest = F.udf(findNearest, T.StringType())
toLookUp = asinscanpy.withColumn("Epoch", F.unix_timestamp(F.col("ScanDate")))\
                     .select("Asin", "US_Rank", "ParentAsin", "NoBB", "ScanDate", "Timestamp", "Epoch").where(F.col("ParentAsin").isNull()).where(F.col("ScanDate") >= '2020-10-01').where(F.col("US_Rank") > 0.0)\
                     .withColumn("ParentAsin", udf_FindNearest(F.col("Asin"), F.col("US_Rank"), F.col("Epoch").cast(T.StringType())))
```